# So slow to push 16,000,000 token by pyapns 0.4.0

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications

I try push 2000 token every one notify() by pyapns 0.4.0.

- All token have 16,000,000.
- Using pyapns 0.4.0
- Run the python on mac .
- Delete the twistd.log.* at first.
- Call notify() for 2000 token every times
- 5 apps Alternating pushed, app have different aphid.

I found some problem:

- 16000000 token are presented in 1 hour , but the click report only have 1000 in 2 hours,
  and click report = 4000 in 24 hours. 
  You know, the old version of java push program, average get clicks is 40000.
- Speed ​​seems to be very slow, 24 hours continues to push.

I think maybe something wrong, And I submit this question into pyapns github 
https://github.com/samuraisam/pyapns/issues/64 for two days.
But no answer :(

Maybe you can have any suggest?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your python code?

Comment: no,python client is ok.
16000000 token are presented in 1 hour.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "24 hours continues to push"?

Comment: thank ,but i think you have never used pyapns.
pyapns is a server, i write the client.